# Proving $\frac {2n}{(a+b)^n} \le \frac {1}{a^n} + \frac {1}{b^n}$ for $a,b>0, n\in\mathbb{N}$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

prove using induction:

$$ \frac {2n}{(a+b)^n} \le \frac {1}{a^n} + \frac {1}{b^n} $$

$$a,b \gt 0  ,  n \in N$$

my attempt:

1. base $n=1$:

   $$ \frac {2}{(a+b)} \le \frac {1}{a} + \frac {1}{b}$$

$$2ab \le b(a+b) + a(a+b)$$

$$2ab \le ab + b^2 + a^2 + ab$$

$$0 <= a^2 + b^2$$

sum of $2$ not negatives, done.

2. assume it's right for $n=k \in N$.......

$$ \frac {2k}{(a+b)^k} \le \frac {1}{a^k} + \frac {1}{b^k}$$

3. prove for $n=k+1$......

$$ \frac {2(k+1)}{(a+b)^{k+1}} \le \frac {1}{a^{k+1}} + \frac {1}{b^{k+1}}$$

i've tried various things... and get stuck everytime.

this is the attempt mimicking what the lecturer/teaching aid do usually with such problems (problems without parameters tho)...

$$ \frac {2(k+1)}{(a+b)^{k+1}} = $$

$$ \frac {1}{(a+b)} \times \left( \frac {2k}{(a+b)^k} + \frac {2}{(a+b)^k} \right) = $$

$$\left(M + \frac {2}{(a+b)^k} \right) \times \frac {1}{(a+b)}$$

go back to the assumption...

$$M \le \frac {1}{a^k} + \frac {1}{b^k}$$

$$M + \frac {2}{(a+b)^k} \le \frac {1}{a^k} + \frac {1}{b^k} + \frac {2} {(a+b)^k}$$

$$\left( M + \frac {2}{(a+b)^k} \right) \times \frac {1}{a+b} \le \left( \frac {1}{a^k} + \frac {1}{b^k} + \frac {2} {(a+b)^k} \right) \times \frac {1}{a+b}$$

now we need to prove...

$$\left( \frac {1}{a^k} + \frac {1}{b^k} + \frac {2} {(a+b)^k} \right) \times\frac {1}{a+b} \le \frac {1}{a^{k+1}} + \frac {1}{b^{k+1}}$$

no matter how i try messing around with this... i reach a dead end.

please help.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange.  It will be very helpful if you carefully typeset your mathematics.  Most of this is done by simply enclosing equations and the like with a $ at the beginning and end.  There is a quick reference here to help with more details: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: done, sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: @TravisJ Just for future reference, [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is really the link you want to be giving to new users or other users not typesetting their questions correctly. Also, in comments, you can avoid pasting naked links like so: [your link](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) may be hyperlinked by `[your link](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)`.

Comment: @MagicMan, thanks for the tips.  I will do that in the future.

Comment: @TravisJ No problem! Nice answer btw, +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Direct Proof

First, I would re-write the inequality so that you want to show $2n\leq \frac{(a+b)^{n}}{a^n}+\frac{(a+b)^{n}}{b^n}$.  Then, we will use two facts which I will prove before finishing.

**Fact 1:** Since $a,b>0$ it follows that $(a+b)^{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}a^{i}b^{i}\geq \binom{n}{1}ab^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n-1}a^{n-1}b=n(ab^{n-1}+ba^{n-1})$.  (Here I've used the Binomial theorem and just left off some positive terms, so the sum was made smaller.  I could put strict inequality if I like.)

**Fact 2:** Since $a,b>0$ it follows that $\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)\geq 2$.  This can be seen as follows:

\begin{align*}
0 &\leq (b-a)^{2} = b^2 - 2ab + a^2 \\
\Rightarrow 2ab &\leq a^{2}+b^{2} \\
\Rightarrow 2   &\leq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}
\end{align*}

Now, putting these two facts to use:
\begin{align*}
\frac{(a+b)^{n}}{a^{n}} + \frac{(a+b)^{n}}{b^{n}} &\geq \frac{n(ab^{n-1}+ba^{n-1})}{a^{n}} + \frac{n(ab^{n-1}+ba^{n-1})}{b^{n}} \\
&\geq n\left(\frac{ba^{n-1}}{a^{n}}+\frac{ab^{n-1}}{b^{n}}\right) \\
&=n\left(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}\right) \\
&\geq 2n.
\end{align*}

### Inductive Proof

**Base Case:** (sure)

The key fact that we will need is that $(a+b)^{n}\geq a^{n}$ and $(a+b)^{n}\geq b^{n}$.  This is only true when $a,b>0$.

**Inductive Step:** We know that $2n\leq (a+b)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a^{n}}+\frac{1}{b^{n}}\right)$ and we want to show that $2n+2=2(n+1)\leq (a+b)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{b^{n+1}}\right)$.

The first thing (as you rightly did) is that we need to make our inductive hypothesis useful by pulling out something that looks like it.

\begin{align*}
(a+b)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{b^{n+1}}\right) &=(a+b)^{n}\left(\frac{a+b}{a^{n+1}}+\frac{a+b}{b^{n+1}}\right) \\
&=(a+b)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a^{n}}+\frac{1}{b^{n}}\right) + (a+b)^{n}\left(\frac{b}{a^{n+1}}+\frac{a}{b^{n+1}}\right) \\
&\geq 2n + (a^{n}+b^{n})\left(\frac{b}{a^{n+1}}+\frac{a}{b^{n+1}}\right) \\
&\geq 2n + \frac{a^{n}b}{a^{n+1}} + \frac{ab^{n}}{b^{n+1}} \text{ (selective distribution)} \\
&= 2n + \frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b} \\
&\geq 2n + 2 \\
&=2(n+1).
\end{align*}

Here, we again used the fact that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\geq 2$ that I referenced in the other solution.  If it wasn't clear, the selective distribution means that I dropped the middle terms of my "FOIL"ing... i.e. I multiplied only the first two terms together and the last two terms together; the result is smaller because I dropped the middle terms that were positive.

Comment: thanks for your time. im afraid however, we are not expected to use your method. but use plain mathematical induction. (without knowledge of the binomial theorem).

Comment: @ckid, no problem (answering questions is usually fun).  If something doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll clarify.  If it helps, when I worked this on paper, I worked backwards (starting with the binomial theorem expansion, then proved the $a/b+b/a$ fact once I realized I needed it).  I didn't think I'd be able to throw away so much of the expansion and still get the inequality.

Comment: @ckid, ahh... I missed the induction part.  I think about that a little more and see if I can give you any hints/direction.  At least you can be confident that the inequality is in fact true.

Comment: @ckid, I added an inductive proof to the solution.  It now contains the solution both ways.

Comment: awesome stuff there. thanks!   it's a few levels over what's expected in the course (use of helper facts, or selective distribution)... i'll post an answer shortly.. can you check it?

Comment: @ckid, sure.  The use of "helper" facts is really just what I needed to show along the way.  I get a step 1 is true if ... and then I have to prove the ... (writing it as a helper fact just makes the exposition clearer imho).  The selective distribution is just a way of masking a step.  You could write out all the terms and then just drop the ones you don't need on the next step.  Again, it's a "concise" way of writing that isn't really necessary.

Comment: @ckid, I saw that you are fairly new to math stackexchange.  I hope you will not delete this question (some new users delete questions once they are answered).  The point of asking/answering questions is that we build up a library of good questions/answers.  This helps other people learn (especially when similar questions/answers can be linked to).  It's late for me, so I'll be happy to look at your proof in the morning.

Comment: i won't delete it. this can surely help others.